# javascript function , if input change

Tags: javascript, function, html-select, onchange

I coded this today, but when i use my dropdown i doesn't work...
it works fine when I'm writing the numbers myself.
Why?!

```
  function favBrowser() {
    var mylist=document.getElementById('myList');
    document.getElementById('favorite').value=mylist.value;
}
 function bar() {
document.write('Hello World!');


<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
    <option></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>  
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
<p>heheheh: <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20" oninput="return bar()" onValueChanged="return bar()" value=""></p>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write` after the document has been loaded/rendered. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
function favBrowser(list) {
    document.getElementById('favorite').value=list.value;
}


<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser(this)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>  
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
<p>heheheh: <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20" value=""></p>
```

Comment: when i use that my dropdown doesnt print de value from dropdown , only undefined ? ;o

Comment: You mean the input value doesn't print the value from the dropdown? Can you please show the onchange you used?

Answer (score 0):

select elements don't have a value, option elements in it have a value. Try the following instead :

```
document.getElementById('favorite').value=mylist.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
```

not tested, but that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Having this code html code:

```
<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser(this.value)">
    <option></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>  
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="favorite" size="20" value=""/>
```

You can do the next:

```
function favBrowser(val) {
     document.getElementById('favorite').value=val;
}
```

Every time that you changes the value of drop down list, automaticly changes the value of input because, you are sending the value of drop down list as param.

Comment: my problem is , when my dropdown changes the value nothing happens , but when i write my own value in de input document.write('Hello World!'); displays

Comment: Dont use document.write after the page loaded.

Comment: document.write was only a thing i wrote to se the change when input has an value :)

Comment: but document.write overwrite all data that you had in a document

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no event `onValueChanged`; you're looking for `onchange`.

The reason why `bar()` is not being triggered when your drop-down script changes the value of `favorite` is because `oninput` is triggered when the value of the element is changed through the user interface (not a script), and `onchange` is triggered when `blur` occurs (that is, the `input` element loses focus). So, in order to get the results you want, you'll need to call `bar()` from `favBrowser()`:

```
function favBrowser() {
  var mylist=document.getElementById('myList');
  document.getElementById('favorite').value=mylist.value;
  bar();
}
```

Comment: hmmm , can u write an example? I'm new on this :(

Comment: The point is, you can't use `oninput` or `onchange` to do something after a script changes the value of an element like you're trying to do. Instead you need to just have the script do it.